# How to strip white space between paragraph tags with jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I strip the space between the `</p>` and `</p>` so that when the title is clicked, the content of the `.html();` will be set into the `.question` div? The content of the `.html()` is generated dynamically and comes through with space between the paragraph tags. I should be able to either run a regex or something similar, but using `$.trim()` only works on the beginning and end of a string, not in between.

```
<a id="title">click me</a>
<div class="question"></div>

$('#title').click(function() {
  $('.question, .mobile-answer').html('<p class="header">Title</p><p>Content of question</p>

    < p > more content goes here < /p>

    < p > even more content goes here < /p>
    ')
  });
```

JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/t38toy6y/)

Answer (score 1):

If your string is

```
str = '<p class="header">Title</p><p>Content of question</p>

    < p > more content goes here < /p>

    < p > even more content goes here < /p>
    '
```

Do:

```
str.replace(/\s*(>|<)\s*/g,"$1")
```

Result:

```
"<p class="header">Title</p><p>Content of question</p><p>more content goes here</p><p>even more content goes here</p>"
```

https://regex101.com/r/DuEA31/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to remove whitespace between `</p>` and `<p>`. Assuming the dynamic content is in a variable called `content`:

```
content = content.replace(/< *\/p *>\s+< *p *>/g, '<p></p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try?

```
// remove whitespace after tags
str.replace(/\>[\t ]+$/g, ">");
```

Source: https://jaketrent.com/post/remove-whitespace-html-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Due to issues with SEO, I have to simply set the content into a toggled state in a div and hide/show based on which link is clicked. This also keeps the data from needing to be filtered with regex.